# JavaScript libraries for converting curves to/from EWKT and GeoJSON

Tags: javascript, well-known-text, curved, circularstring, ewkt

Are there any JavaScript libraries that can convert EWKT/WKT curve geometries (as defined by PostGIS) to GeoJSON or similar? That is, libraries that generate a linear approximation of a CIRCULARSTRING and a COMPOUNDCURVE, for instance.

I also need information about the curve geometry itself: the center, radius and angles of each curve.

Comment: If you have control over the actual export, use an [`ST_CurveToLine`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_CurveToLine.html) wrapper for your geometries.

Comment: Yes, I will be doing that, but I also need to information about the curve geometries themselves in order to render with HTML canvas - updated question